# moment generating function uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, moment-generating-functions

I'm trying to prove a simple example of MGF for $E[x]$ for a simple RV with uniform distribution over range $[0,10]$ but not sure where I'm getting stuck:

$A(t) = E[e^{tx}] = \int_{0,10}e^{tx}dx/10$ **note Riemann Sum not Lebesgue*

My understanding is then you take the derivative $d/dt$ of $A(t)$ but when doing so I get:

$ (e^{10t} - 1)/t - (e^{10t} - 1)/10t$ How does this equal $5$ which is $E[x]$ given the above definition of $x$ being uniformly distributed from $[0,10]$?

Comment: Limit of the derivative as $t\to 0$ does equal $5$.

Comment: Shouldn't the derivative be $\frac{e^{10 t}}{t}-\frac{e^{10 t}-1}{10 t^2}$ ?